# Get all input fields inside div (without JS library)

Tags: javascript, textinput

What's the easiest way to get all input fields inside a div without using a javascript library like jQuery?
Similar to this jQuery snippet:

```
var inputs = $('#mydiv :input');
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').getElementsByTagName('input')
```

Answer (score 20):

`querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` will fetch the details of what you're expecting easily.

```
var divElem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var inputElements = divElem.querySelectorAll("input, select, checkbox, textarea");
```

It will give all the input, select, textarea elements in array format.

Comment: You don't need "checkbox" - it's an "input" element. Barring that this should be the accepted answer because Roy Sharon's answer doesn't include text areas and select lists.

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('mydiv').getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are on modern browsers (ie9+) you can take advantage of [`querySelectorAll‎`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll‎('#myDiv input');
```

or if you already have the div, you can use it directly

```
var inputs = myDiv.querySelectorAll('input');
var inputs = myDiv.getElementByTagName('input');
```

either will work. To serialize you can do this once you have your inputs

```
var values = {}
for (const input of inputs){
   values[input.name] = input.value
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName)

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Comment: Can I serialize this `inputs`?